# Nodejs IPV6 IP Address inconsistences on GET request

Tags: node.js

UPDATE:

So this works as expected if I add the following:

```js
const options = {
    ...standardStuff,
    family: 6,
}
```

Adding the `family: 6` option means it works as expected. So I supposed my question changes to why?? From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) it states:

```
IP address family to use when resolving host or hostname.
Valid values are 4 or 6. When unspecified, both IP v4 and v6 will be used.
```

Whixh would leave me to conclude I wouldnt need to as `IPV6` is being used anyway. And why would `curl` etc not matter?

---

Have a `zone lockdown` rule on `cloudflare` for a `cname` we have registered with my `IPV6` address added to the white list. I got this from googling `whatsmyip`.

I also added my companies VPN ip address with is in the `ipv4` format.

When I curl this endpoint I receive the expeted `200` - however when I run a request via `nodejs` I receive a `403`.

This is even stranger as I am able to access the endpoint via `golang`, `insomnia`, `curl` and I am also able to access it via `nodejs` when I am connected to an `ipv4` network - e.g VPN or if I tether my phone to my laptop.

```sh
curl https://my-restricted-endpoint.com 
# 200
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://my-restriced-endpoint.com")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
    // 200
}
```

```js
const requestAsync = (options: RequestOptions | string | URL): Promise<number> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = request(options, (res) => {
            if (typeof res.statusCode !== 'number') {
                reject('no status code returned');
                return;
            }
            resolve(res.statusCode);
        });

        req.on('error', (error) => {
            reject(error);
        });

        req.on('timeout', () => {
            reject('request timed out');
        });

        req.end();
    });
};

const statusCode = await requestAsync('https://my-restricted-endpoint.com')
// returns 200 on VPN or thetherd to phone with an ipv4 ip address
// returns 403 otherwise
```

My knowlege of netowkring and IPV4/6 is limited to nonexistent - but feel like this is the cause with something `nodejs` is doing with the request.

I have also tried using `axios`

Comment: Kindly share the link to docs regarding "IP address family to use when resolving host or hostname."

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I only whitelist my `ipv6` address then I need to force `nodejs` to resolve the hostname to `ipv6` by setting `{family: 6}`.

If I add both my `ipv6` and `ipv4` to whitelist then I can leave that option alone.

It seems that `golang`, `curl`, and `insomnia` in which I was using implement [RFC6555](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6555) 'Happy Eyeballs' which means that `ipv6` will be used first and only on failure would `ipv4` be used. It was why these worked and `nodejs` did not. From what I can gather `nodejs` does not implement this which means that due no whitelisting my `ipv4` address on `cloudflare` it would fail.